# How to send and receive messages using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating a chat application using XMPP Framework in iPhone. I wish to know the process for sending and receiving messages. Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure the XMPP framework has a documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick google search reveals many [XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), either C/C++ or ObjC. Perhaps http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/ would be a good starting point, though I haven't tried it personally.

Answer (score 10):

Download [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) and unzip it. There are several folders inside. Open the 'Xcode' folder > open 'iPhoneXMPP' folder > click on 'iPhoneXMPP.xcodeproj' > run it. It asks login credential first. Upon successful login, it will show your buddy list. It works fine for gmail. There is one call back method which is called for every incoming message:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from] xmppStream:sender     managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];
        NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [m setObject:body forKey:@"msg"];
        [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {          
             NSLog(@"Applications are in active state");
             //send the above dictionary where ever you want
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Applications are in Inactive state");
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=count;
            localNotification.alertBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From:"%@\n\n%@",from,body];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
             //send the above dictionary where ever you want
        }
    }
}
```

For sending message we have to write our own method where ever you want:

```
-(void)sendMessage
{
    NSString *messageStr =messageField.text;

    if([messageStr length] > 0)
    {              
        NSLog(@"Message sending fron Gmail");
        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:messageStr];
        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"destination address"];
        [message addChild:body];
        NSLog(@"message1%@",message);

        [[self appDelegate].xmppSream sendElement:message];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Sending the message in groups/Room  below is the snippet

```
XMPPMessage *message = [XMPPMessage message];
[message addBody:@"123"];
[self.currentRoom sendMessage:message1]; 

Where self.currentRoom is XMPPRoom
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending message from `Room/Group` then use this code for sending messages.

```
[xmppRoom sendMessage:@"Hi All"];
```

Don't need to send the messages through `xmppStream`. This Single line of code works perfectly for me.

Comment: `@"Hi All"` exists as a `NSString` not a `XMPPMessage`. Incompatible for input to `sendMessage` method. You will receive this error: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'XMPPMessage *'

Comment: Hi Keith OYS, Sorry I don't know which XMPP Library you are using but I did cross check this under XMPPRoom Class. Its 

-(void)sendMessage:(NSString *)msg;

I have used the same. Let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: The latest XMPPFramework is using `- (void)sendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message;` in `XMPPRoom` class. As such, you'd need to initialise an `XMPPMessage` first.

Comment: yes you are right Keith OYS, I am using Old XMPPFramework. but In new one We have to Initialise XMPPMessage First :-)

Comment: No worries, just a heads up. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to send message via XMPPFramework in Swift 3

```
let user = XMPPJID(string: "user@jabjab.de")
let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: user)
msg?.addBody("Message to send")
self.xmppStream.send(msg)
```